# Trying to create a virtual desktop collection, but the template doesn't show

Tags: remote-desktop-services, rds, windows-server-2016, vdi

First time building a Windows Server 2016 with a friend.

Everything went really smooth until deploying VDI.

We want to host all the roles (including a DC) on a single server, since this is for a small company.

We had some trouble installing the RDS roles but eventually it succeeded.

Now we want to add a Virtual Desktop Collection, but the template doesn't show in the wizard.

We created a Win10 VM using hyper-v and syspreped it.

What are we doing wrong, why doesn't the template show in the wizard? Or could the problem be something else we did wrong?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqwaU.png)

Answer (score -1):

You must have a separate server for AD DC role since it cannot work with Hyper-V on the same server.